# Create a database table depends on XML

Tags: sql-server

Is there an option to create a database table (SQL Server) automatically depends on a large XML data? Instead of creating the table manually.
, let say you have the xml with 50 nodes
 i need a pattern to create a table with the mentioned 50 columns automatically for one time Because i have a huge xml tree . My needs is to save time

Comment: Please provide further detail on how you are importing your XML data.

Comment: Im importing the xml from a webservice, my question is , let say you have the xml <id>1</id><name>test</name><age>50</age> , i need a pattern to create a table with the mentioned three column above . Because i have a huge xml tree . My needs is to save time

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Liquibase for XML based Database management on SQL Server.

First, you need to integrate your code base with Liquibase then need to convert your existing XML to Liquibase version XML like below. So, you can start to manage your database changes (including DDL and DML operations) via a DBMS Tool.

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="bob">
        <createTable tableName="department">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean"                     
              defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
   </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/xml_format.html
https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/tutorials/mssql.html